# How to read a from a file while executing code

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

Related config:

```
noremap <F5> :make<CR>
noremap <F6> :!./%<<CR>
noremap <F7> :!./%< 2>/dev/null<CR>
```

The problem is while running the program with <kbd>F6</kbd> when I paste input from clipboard it messes up the output and before all the input is pasted there is already something printed which makes it a bit difficult to read quickly.

A workaround is to read from a file, like `./<filename> < in` but i was not able to map this command to key.

```
noremap <F8> :!./%<CR> < in
```

I am a beginner and don't know much about these configurations.
Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit:**
For copy pasting from clipboard, i have the following lines in `.vimrc` from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480829/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-vim-of-bash-on-windows.
I am using WSL on windows.

```
vmap <C-c> y:new ~/.vimbuffer<CR>VGp:x<CR> \| :!cat ~/.vimbuffer \| clip.exe <CR><CR>
map <C-Shift-v> :r ~/.vimbuffer<CR>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, how can you paste input from clipboard while you run something with `!`, it's not asynchronous.

Comment: it opens up terminal, in which i can either type or paste.

Comment: Have a look https://ibb.co/dPsCwrv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `map`, you should do it with `command`, `command` allows you to input filename as `args`.

```
command -nargs=1 -complete=file Exe !./%< <<args>
```

`:h <args>` will be expanded to your input filename. You can execute it like this:

```
:Exe input_filename
```

If you are using vim8, you may try this:

```
command -nargs=1 -complete=file ExeTerminal exec 'terminal bash -c "./%< <<args>"' | wincmd p
```

It's asynchronous, you output will be in a vim terminal buffer.
`:h terminal` see `|` as it's arguments, you need to use `exec` to write multiple commands in 1 line.

**update**

If you want to create a map to just enter filename:

```
nnoremap <f8> :Exe<space>
```

`<space>` is a space.

Comment: +1, Thanks it works. 
Is this possible to map this with key such that i only input the file name?
Is this possible for <kbd>F6</kbd> to run after everything is pasted?

Comment: ./test.cpp: line 3: using: command not found                                                                            ./test.cpp: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('                                                              ./test.cpp: line 5: `int main()'                                                                                                                                                                                                                shell returned 2

Comment: @D.BenKnoble What do you suggest?

Comment: @dedowsdi I am simply tring to execute the executable file i.e. ./test

Comment: I was wrong—I didn’t understand the `<` syntax. But in any case, there’s something wrong with @kayush setup and it isn’t a good fit for [vi.se]. The answer should work.

Comment: `nnoremap <f8> :Exe<space>` is working for me, please edit this. Thanks for the help

Comment: or is Exc there for any other purpose?

Comment: @kayush My bad, it should be `Exe`, i use `ExeExc` in my test case. I also add `-complete=file` in the update, you can `<tab>` complete the input file.

Comment: Cool, Thanks for helping